# Cannot access member from another function c++ class

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt

So basically my code looks like this:

```cpp
void SimpleMQTT::begin() {
    Serial.println("setserver");
    WiFiClient espClient;
    PubSubClient client(espClient);
    client.setServer(this->serverAddress, this->port);
    while(!client.connected()) {
        if (client.connect(this->deviceName)) {
            Serial.println("connected to mqtt");
            client.publish("connecting", "connected");
        } else {
            Serial.println("failed to connect");
        }
    }
    this->client = & client;
    //WORKING
    this->client->publish("connecting","conn2");
}

void SimpleMQTT::broadcast(char* channelName, char* message) {
    Serial.println("broadcasting");
    Serial.println(this->deviceName);
    //NOT WORKING
    this->client->connected();
    Serial.println("after broadcast");
}
```

accessing a member from the function `begin()` works, but accessing the same member from the function `broadcast()` doesn't work.
Arduino is sending an exception to Serial (see screenshot).

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is not working? Error message perhaps?

Comment: Is it possible that in `broadcast()`, `this->client` is not initialized yet?

Comment: There is no error message on compilation while running program on arduino board it's causing exception. I can repost what arduino display on serial but it's telling nothing for me.

Comment: I'ts not sossible becaouse its done fater begin and delay

Comment: Why can't you post the error message? Just type it or post a screenshot.

Comment: Please do NOT post screenshots of errors, they are impossible to search for. Copy and paste the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a dangling pointer issue.
You create the client object on the stack:

```cpp
PubSubClient client(espClient);
```

then refer to it:

```cpp
this->client = & client;
```

However, once the function `SimpleMQTT::begin()` exits, `client` is deleted along with the rest of the function's stack.

You should create the client object on the heap instead.
Change the code to:

```cpp
void SimpleMQTT::begin() {
    Serial.println("setserver");
    WiFiClient* espClient = new WiFiClient();
    PubSubClient* client = new PubSubClient(espClient); // Allocate an object on the heap
    client.setServer(this->serverAddress, this->port);
    while(!client->connected()) {
        if (client->connect(this->deviceName)) {
            Serial.println("connected to mqtt");
            client->publish("connecting", "connected");
        } else {
            Serial.println("failed to connect");
        }
    }
    this->client = client;
    this->client->publish("connecting","conn2");
}
```

`espClient` should also be a member of your class.

Here is a more elaborate explanation of [danling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).